# User Registration and Authentication to a Database using Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, node.js

I'm new to Web Dev and I came across a problem. I was wondering if there's a Javascript Framework that will allow me to register and authenticate users to a database like when using PHP and MySql.

Also, when the user is granted access to the site, such user will be required to upload files that will be written to the local filesystem of that server.

Can this be done with Javascript or some sort of Javascript Framework, or is it better just for me to learn PHP and do it in a normal LAMP stack? Or perhaps Ruby on Rails?

I have been searching online but the majority of results are leaning towards PHP & MySql.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see you included the Node.js tag in your question, so you must already have some idea that this it *is* possible to do this using JavaScript.  And your intuitions are absolutely correct: you can do anything using JavaScript and Node.js on the server that you can do using PHP or Python, including user authentication and interfacing with databases.  Node.js offers another benefit for beginners, which is the ability to write both client and server-side apps using a single language -- JavaScript.

The pretty much standard web framework to use in Node.js is called ExpressJS, and it has a very nice plugin for user authentication called PassportJS.

If you'd like to learn how to implement user authentication on ExpressJS yourself, without a plugin, there's a nice tutorial on how to do this at [[1]](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/learn-to-use-the-new-router-in-expressjs-4)

Also, since you also included the AngularJS tag, I should mention the [satellizer](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer) project, which offers a ready-to-use authentication module for AngularJS, with the server side available not only in NodeJS, but also PHP, Python, and Java.

As noted in a neighboring response, you can also use a solution like [parse.com](http://parse.com) or [Firebase](http://firebase.com), which are companies that manage the server-side user authentication and databases for you, and provide you with an easy client-side Javascript library to use.  However, these services come at a price, literally, although they do also offer a free tier for introductory use.

One final possibility worth exploring is MeteorJS, which allows you to write client and server-side not only in the same language (JavaScript) but also using the same framework, and within the same application.  MeteorJS also has full user authentication built-in, which makes it very easy to make a quick start.

1. http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/learn-to-use-the-new-router-in-expressjs-4

Comment: Eric,

Thanks a lot for all the information! I just have one doubt though, is ExpressJS part of Node.js or are they two different frameworks?

Comment: Node.js isn't really a framework, it's more of a platform (technically, it's a "runtime environment").  And ExpressJS is a framework (that runs on the Node.js platform).  So no, ExpressJS isn't part of Node.js, you have to install it separately (once you install Node.js, you'll have access to a tool called npm that will help you easily install any Node.js applications).

Comment: Awesome! That gives me a way better understanding of Node.js and ExpressJS. So, ExpressJS is the one that connects to either a MySql or MongoDB database and does the login authentication and/or user registration, correct?

Comment: Well, it's actually a bit more complex than that.  The database drivers (like for MySQL and Mongo) run on top of NodeJS and can be used in ExpressJS.  For our purposes here, it's probably best to think of Node.js as a programming language like PHP, and ExpressJS like a framework such as Symphony in PHP.  I'd suggesting reading up on Node.js and ExpressJS at their respective sites and then come back here to ask a (separate) question if you have any additional queries.

Comment: Most definitely. I have a lot of reading to do. Thank you again for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of development.

In general, javascript is only used to give more resources to the user's navigation on the site (ex: visual effects).

As you're starting out, I advise you to start studying the part of the server-side login. For security purposes who confirms whether the user is logged in or not is always the server.

Some developers prefer PHP, other developers love Ruby on Rails. Maybe your best friend prefer Python... It is your choice, they both are easy.

Answer (score 0):

Users are authenticated by the server against some database. Your client app only gets a token signifying that a user has authenticated. On the web that token is an authentication cookie, which gets sent with every HTTP request. The cookie contains cryptographically signed authentication token. The validation of that token is done by the server (which holds the key).

So, yes, you need to learn some server technology, like PHP.

You may also want to take a look at a service like [Parse.com](http://parse.com) - it was designed for mobile apps, but they support Javascript as well. They remove the need (in some cases) to write your own services.